# Linear algebra: Proving uniqueness and existence of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $W$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space with an inner product. Show there exists a unique real-valued function $V(\mathbf{x_1},...,\mathbf{x_k})$ of $k$-tuples of vectors of $W$ such that:

1) Exchanging $\mathbf{x_i}$ with $\mathbf{x_j}$ does not change the value of $V$.

2)Replacing $\mathbf{x_i}$ by $\mathbf{x_i}+c\mathbf{x_j}$ (for $j\ne i$) does not change the value of $V$

3)Replacing $\mathbf{x_i}$ by $\lambda \mathbf{x_i}$ multiplies the value of $V$ by $\left| \lambda \right |$

4)If the $\mathbf{x_i}$ are orthonormal , then $V(\mathbf{x_1},...,\mathbf{x_k})$=1

You may think this function gives the $k$-dimensional volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the $k$-tuple $(\mathbf{x_1},...,\mathbf{x_k})$. The book gives the following hints:

a) Prove uniqueness. [Hint: Use the Gram-Schmidt process]

b) Prove existence. [Hint: if $f:W\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear transformation that carries an orthonormal basis to an orthonormal basis, then $f$ carries the inner product on $W$ to the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$]

How can I apply these hints, in particular b) ? I think I could use the function $V(\mathbf{x_1},...,\mathbf{x_k})=[\det(X^{tr}\cdot X)]^{1/2}$ where $X$ is the $n$ by $k$ matrix $X=[\mathbf{x_1} ... \mathbf{x_k}]$, showing it satisfies the four conditions up here, however I still have to prove uniqueness. The book says nothing about seeking such a function, so I think I should only prove existence. What do you suggest?

Comment: You're probably on the right track with that function. The hints are valid though. You can prove existence and uniqueness by using the properties given without using the determinant. In fact, this is now one can prove that the function determinant exists without really writing the formula.

Comment: How can I use those hints?

Comment: I do not have the time right now to write an answer. Look at the Gramm-Schmidt process. In that process the initial operations are only operations of type 2) , so there is no change in the value of the function. Changes come when you normalize, whcih is an operation of type 3). If you write things down and use 4, you get an explicit formula, which gives unicity.

Comment: So, take your time, I'll wait for your answer :)

Comment: @BeniBogosel Did you find the answer?